# Cannot hear music on my iPhone 5S

Tags: iphone, audio, sound-volume

I can't hear sound in my iPhone. I can't listen to music or any sound on my device. I'm frustrated trying to solve this.

Comment: Are you using headphones or are you having trouble with the speaker?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Ask Different!

A few things to try:

- Make sure the mute switch is off and working - on the top left side of the phone there's a switch that has a red backing if it's turned on. If it's showing red, toggle it back, and your sound will come back on. Simple :)
- If that does nothing, make sure the switch works. Toggle it back and forth a few times, there should be a popup indicating that sound is now muted. If nothing appears on the screen when the switch is toggled, the switch is probably broken, and you'll need to talk to Apple or your carrier's insurance about getting it fixed.
- I'm guessing you already tried this, but there are two volume settings on iOS, one for the ringer and one for apps and music. If you just use the volume rocker in most places, your ringer volume changes. If you use it while music or sound is playing, app volume changes. Make sure that your music/sound volume is up.

Comment: Just to note: if the app is a conventional music/video player, then it can play the track's audio regardless of the mute switch—assuming volume is not set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Do you hear sound with EarPods in? If so, it's likely that your speaker has gone out and needs to be replaced.

Comment: No speaker sound is also commonly caused by dirt deep inside the headphone port, which fools the iPhone into thinking a headphone plug is inserted when it isn't, and thus disconnects the speakers. A magnifying glass and careful work with a toothpick or Q-tip can fix this.